# Error in ACF function: getting all NAs in the result

Tags: r, longitudinal, autocorrelation

Hi I have a longitudinal dataset where we have data on professionals and the Maslach Burnout Inventory Score.

```
The basic data looks like:
data.frame':    1907 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ MBI_1 : num  6 4 2 3 7 5 6 6 6 4 ...
 $ MBI_2 : num  5 6 0 2 5 4 4 5 5 2 ...
 $ MBI_3 : num  4 4 0 2 4 4 1 3 4 2 ...
 $ MBI_4 : num  4 14 7 4 1 9 6 8 9 6 ...
 $ MBI_5 : num  3 12 6 3 1 3 7 7 7 3 ...
 $ MBI_6 : num  8 3 6 3 5 3 5 6 6 4 ...
 $ MBI_7 : num  5 14 8 10 1 10 10 8 8 6 ...
 $ MBI_8 : num  3 2 0 1 4 4 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ MBI_9 : num  2 11 7 6 7 7 5 7 6 4 ...
 $ MBI_10: num  3 10 4 3 4 5 9 6 9 3 ...
 $ MBI_11: num  3 8 4 4 7 7 8 6 8 5 ...
 $ MBI_12: num  6 3 6 6 7 5 4 7 7 2 ...
 $ MBI_13: num  4 6 6 4 6 3 5 4 8 2 ...
 $ MBI_14: num  0 4 0 1 4 3 1 2 3 0 ...
 $ MBI_15: num  3 12 3 3 1 3 8 5 6 3 ...
 $ MBI_16: num  5 5 3 2 2 4 3 1 6 2 ...
 $ MBI_17: num  3 14 9 7 3 9 7 1 9 5 ...
 $ MBI_18: num  3 13 3 6 9 9 4 6 9 3 ...
 $ MBI_19: num  8 6 4 6 9 9 5 8 10 3 ...
 $ MBI_20: num  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 ...
 $ MBI_21: num  5 5 7 5 1 7 7 6 7 4 ...
 $ MBI_22: num  3 12 3 3 1 3 3 6 5 3 ...
```

I have summed up all these scores over the rows and created a new variable called "mbitot" which sums up each persons total over the 22 answers at each point in time (which happens to be 4 visits)

```
This is how it looks:
num [1:1907] 86 169 88 84 89 117 111 112 143 68 ...
```

There are a few NAs there.

Then I ran

```
    library(nlme)
    fit1=gls(mbi`itot~as.factor(visit),data=mss,na.action=na.exclude)
    ACF(fit1,form=~1|ID)
    ##Output i am getting is
    lag ACF
    1   0  NA
    2   1  NA
    3   2  NA
    4   3  NA
    5   4  NA
    6   5  NA
```

First of all, I am unable to figure out why I am getting NAs.
The regression summary is coming out fine and there are no NAs there.
The results of the regression are:
Intercept 95.93, Slope 6.5 with Correlation of -0.89.

Any ideas why I am getting these NAs? Any input would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The regression formula here shows a the Y variable as mbi'itot. This is a typo here. In the actual code, it is correctly mentioned as mbitot.